# How to calculate distance driven by day based on mileage

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to calculate the distance driven based on the mileage. I am grabbing the `MAX` and `MIN` distance per day and subtract that from each other. However this does not use the 'last' mileage from the previous day, so a piece of 'distance' is missing.

How can I grab the 'latest' mileage before the given day and use that as the MIN mileage instead.

**SQL Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3ea7d/7/0

PS: In this fiddle I use a simple 'day' stored as a integer, however in the real implementation this is a date stored as epoch which is then converted to day by `strftime`.

**Desired results:**

```
day      distance
1        300
2        400
3        400
```

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've included my desired results in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the previous day's maximum, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
WITH td as (
      SELECT t.day, MAX(t.distance) as maxd, MIN(t.distance) mind
      FROM trips t
      GROUP BY t.day
     )
SELECT td.day,
       (maxd -
        COALESCE( (SELECT MAX(td2.maxd)
                   FROM td td2
                   WHERE td2.day < td.day
                  ),
                  td.mind
                )
       ) as diff
FROM td;
```

Most databases support the ANSI standard `LAG()` function, which would make this much easier.  Alas, SQLite does not support it.

Comment: Awesome! Is it possible to replace the correlated subquery with a JOIN?

Comment: @tomwassing . . . You can replace it with a `join` and `group by`, but that would probably have even worse performance.